# Getting out after a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I have a random function that creates two lists with random numbers ranging between 1 to 11.

I want to check if any of those two lists of random numbers contain numbers, any number from 9 to 11.

If numbers 9-11 are contained in any of the lists, I want the program to print a message and then stop the iteration. In other words, I would like the message to be displayed once.

I've tried the following, but the code prints the message multiple times during the execution.

```py
split = [9,10,11]

container = []

for count in range (2):
    rand_num = random.randrange (1, 11 + 1)
    print(f"player_1 card is : {rand_num}")
    container.append(rand_num)
      
for place in container:
    if place in split :      
        print("you can go double down")
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `break` statement: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_break.asp

Comment: The title is incorrectly named by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `break` statement inside your loop.
`break` it when a certain condition is met.

```
# Use of break statement inside the loop

for val in "string":
    if val == "i":
        break
    print(val)

print("The end")
```

outputs:

```
s
t
r
The end
```

Read this on [breaking out of loops in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue).

This is [another good article](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/) on working with indefinite loops

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is checked each time the for loop is run. You can use a break statement to exit the loop after finding it the first time. e.g:

```
for place in container:
    if place in split:
        print("you can go double down")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
import random
split = [9,10,11]
container = []
for i in range (1):
    rand_num = random.sample(range(1,12),2)
    print ( f"player_1 card is : {rand_num}" )
    container.append(rand_num)
  
for place in split:
    if place in rand_num :      
        print("you can go double down")
```

Comment: Great use of "sample" here. Thanks a lot